# how to get doctrine2 entitymanager in slmqueue job?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm going to use SlmQueue (https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueueDoctrine).

How can I get doctrine2 entitymanager inside job class?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make this like this:

```
        class DistributeNewsJob extends AbstractJob implements QueueAwareInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
        {   
            use QueueAwareTrait;

            public function execute()
            {
                 // job code

            }

            private $entityManager;
            private function getEntityManager()
            {
                if (null === $this->entityManager) {    
                    $this->entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                }
                return $this->entityManager;
            }

            private $services;

            public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
            {
                $this->services = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
            }

            public function getServiceLocator()
            {
                return $this->services;
            }

            public function dispatch(Request $request, Response $response = null)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this :

You can use `ObjectManagerAwareInterface` from doctrine module

```
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ProvidesObjectManager as ProvidesObjectManagerTrait;

class EmailJob extends AbstractJob implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    use ProvidesObjectManagerTrait;
}
```

That way you have ObjectManager in your job.